# Subdocument does not update - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update a subdocument of the parent document.

I have a document called "Post" and I reference the "User" document like this:

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  
  title: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },

},
  { collection: 'posts' })


const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

I'm trying to change the name, for example of whoever posted it. The name field is in "User".

I'm trying to change it this way:

```
exports.update = async (req, res) => {
//find user by its id, update its post with what's in req.body
Post.findById(req.body.id, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result)
    if (!err) {
      if (!result){
        res.status(404).send('User was not found');
      }
      else{
        result.user.nome = "User Name";
        result.markModified("user"); 
        result.save(function(saveerr, saveresult) {
          if (!saveerr) {
            res.status(200).send(saveresult);
          } else {
            res.status(400).send(saveerr.message);
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).send(err.message);
    }
  }).populate("user");
}
```

This is my route.js

```
app.put(
    "/api/produtor/update",
    controller.update
  );
```

When I run it on the postman, I get status 200 and the name appears modified in the return, but it is not saved in the bank.

**I would appreciate it if someone could help me analyze it!**

Answer (score 0):

This might be outdated but as per this GitHub [comment](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3416#issuecomment-146293915), this might not be  possible out of the box.

I would suggest to update the `User` by using `User` schema instead of going through the `Post` Schema.